# Setting NSURLRequestCachePolicy and NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

I'm creating an `NSURLSession` with a sessionConfiguration where I have explicitly set the `requestCachePolicy` and `URLCache`.

```
sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;
sessionConfiguration.URLCache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
```

A request is created and passed as an argument in `NSURLSession` `dataTaskWithRequest:CompletionHandler:` method. The request is constructed like this:

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:kAENServiceNetworkTimeout];
```

**Problem 1:**

Setting up like this, no `fsCachedData` Folder is created on disk and cached data is not used. If the request is created simply using:

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

The cache is created on disk, and the image is used as expected. Is this a bug in Apple's code?

**Problem 2:**

In neither of these cases is the `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:` delegate method called.  Are their situations under which this would be the case?

**Update:**

I've pushed an example project to Github, https://github.com/mattmorton/cache-testing

Comment: Is my understanding of NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad incorrect?  Is the data returned in the response not cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problem 1:***

I think my understanding of the NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad was incorrect. In this case the response is not cached.

***Problem 2:***

From Apple header for NSURLSession in the NSURLSessionAsynchronousConvenience category:

> data task convenience methods...create tasks that bypass the normal delegate calls for response and data delivery, and provide a simple cancelable asynchronous interface to receiving data.

I am using a convenience method handler, hence why the delegate method is not being called.